# Why pip install --upgrade reinstalling package even if latest version already installed?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

**I have written a script to automatically update installed python packages. This script runs on application startup every time and makes sure that if new python package version is available it downloads and installs it. I am using following line in my script to achieve this -**

#### Case - I

```
python -m pip install --upgrade my_pyPackage
```

With above line script works perfectly fine. It gives following output if the package is already installed -

```
Looking in indexes: <pypi_artifactory_url>
Requirement already satisfied: my_pyPackage in c:\path\to\site-packages (4.0.3)
```

#### Case - II

However, if I modify my command to -

```
python -m pip install --upgrade my_pyPackage --target <path\to\custom\dir>
```

This script works fine if new version is available. But if even if new version is not available, pip installs cached version again and again into target directory.

Output is as below -

```
Looking in indexes: <pypi_artifactory_url>
Collecting my_pyPackege
  Using cached my_pyPackege-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: my_pyPackege
Successfully installed my_pyPackege-4.0.3
```

**I want to avoid/override Case-II behavior and expect output to be as it is in Case-I.
Any solution or better approach for this issue?**

Comment: It looks like pip doesn't bother to check what is already installed at the target when the `--target` option is used.  Seems like a bug in pip, might be worth creating an issue on their github page.

Comment: I think it's on purpose that the dependencies are not checked when `--target` is used. Or at least it was not deemed necessary and/or never implemented. I also think maintainers of _pip_ want to move away from / deprecate flags such as `--target` `--prefix` and things like that. Some recent related discussion here: https://discuss.python.org/t/installing-packages-close-to-the-project-root/6915

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (easier, IMO) way is to simply use the pip executable that's in the virtualenv itself.

```
path\to\target_dir\Scripts\pip install --upgrade  my_pyPackage
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @sinoroc

Replacing `python -m pip install--upgrade  my_pyPackage --target ...` by below lines resolved my issue.

```
python -m venv target_dir_name path\to\target_dir
path\to\target_dir\Scripts\activate.bat
python -m pip install --upgrade my_pyPackage 
path\to\target_dir\Scripts\deactivate.bat
```